# build model structure - Fat Free Framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I'm creating model structure with f3 but towards to end I stuck.
I cant access to my functions another page.

Here is error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on null
>   [C:/UwAmp/www/test/app/models/User.php:12]

Where is wrong? Is this way good or not?

```
-models
----Model.php
----User.php

-controllers
----Controller.php
----UserController.php
```

UserController.php

```
class UserController extends Controller {


    private $_usermodal;

    public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
    }

    function Register(){

        $this->_usermodal = new User();
        $this->_usermodal->getAll();
    }

}
```

Model.php

```
class Model {

    private $db;

    public function __construct($table){

        $this->db=new DB\SQL(
            'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=database',
            'root',
            'root'
        );

        return new DB\SQL\Mapper($this->db,$table);
    }


}
```

User.php (model)

```
class User extends Model {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct('users');

    }

    public function getAll(){
        $x = $this->db->load('id = 1');
        print_r($x);
    }
}
```

Comment: private $db needs to be protected $db

Comment: You also can't return a new model from a construct, doesn't even make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning a mapper instance from the `__constructor` (which is not possible in PHP), you could extend the framework mapper:

Model.php:

```
class Model extends DB\SQL\Mapper {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct($table) {
        $this->db=new DB\SQL(
            'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=database',
            'root',
            'root'
        );
        parent::__construct($this->db,$table);
    }

}
```

User.php:

```
class User extends Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('users');
    }

    public function getAll() {
        return $this->find('',['order'=>'id']);
    }

}
```

Now you can access your db records using the usual mapper methods:

```
$user = new User;
$user->load(['id=?',1]);
// or
foreach ($user->find(['name LIKE ?','%John%']) as $u)
  echo $u->name;
```

or using your custom methods:

```
foreach ($user->getAll() as $u)
  echo $u->name;
```

This structure can still be improved though as it creates a new `DB\SQL` instance for every fetched record. You could create a central `DB` service and use it by default in `Model`:

Index.php:

```
 $f3->DB = function() {
     if (!Registry::exists('DB')) {
         $db=new DB\SQL(
             'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=database',
             'root','root');
         Registry::set('DB',$db);
     }
     return Registry::get('DB');
 };
```

Model.php:

```
class Model extends DB\SQL\Mapper {

    public function __construct($table,$db=NULL) {
        if (!isset($db)) {
            $f3=\Base::instance();
            $db=$f3->DB();
        }
        parent::__construct($db,$table);
    }

}
```

Comment: which way do you recommend sir? is this logic good or should I use this 
 way ? https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/sql-mapper#Instantiation

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: is it make sense creating models like that? is this right way? what do you recommend me?

Comment: It's really up to you to decide if an architecture makes sense or not. Does it fit your needs? Do you understand how it works? Is it easy to maintain? If yes, then it totally makes sense.